Why output voltage became an irregular sawtooth shape?
Why does the transient output voltage in PSpice simulation turn into an irregular sawtooth shape?
Before today, it was a beautiful curve that could calculate the voltage gain, but suddenly it
became like this.
Here is the circuit.




Given the scale is in nanovolts, the output waveform is basically just 0V with probably some rounding/precision error. Your input voltage appears to also be just 0V, so that kind of makes sense. There is not enough information in the question to answer it - you'll need to figure out what you've changed between before and now. Did you change the voltage input (check that plus its frequency)? Are you using the same mode? Are you running for the same length of time?

Your output is basically 0V. The part of the schematic near the source and back gate does not look connected. I do recall some weirdness with the Orcad schematic editor.
